# Does Qt have a model-driven version of QTabBar or QTabWidget?

Tags: qt, tabs, model-view

I want to create a Qt widget that looks like a `QTabWidget` but where the list of tabs is drawn from a (Qt Model View architecture) data model, like `QListView` etc. Since QTabWidget has to have separate widgets on each page, this will probably be something like a `QTabBar` and a single set of widgets under it (eg some buttons and a `QTreeView`).

- Can `QTabBar` get its list of tabs from a data model? I'm pretty sure not.
- Is there an equivalent widget that can?
- Can you for example make a `QListView` with `flow=LeftToRight` look like a tab bar?

Using Qt4 at the moment. Will consider Qt5.

I'm using PyQt but C++ examples would be fine.

Comment: Surprisingly little of QtGui is model driven, which is unfortunate, because that solution is much more flexible, cleaner and easier to maintain. You can easily make your own GUI element versions, thou it will take a while to refine them. My GUI is almost entirely model driven, although I use QML where development speed is much faster.